# How to commit a file to Bitbucket using Rest API?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, bitbucket-api

I am trying to commit a file to Bitbucket using Rest API from postman, but it shows method not allowed.

Below is the URL which I am trying

**http://URL/projects/CONFIG_MNGMNT/repos/devicegroups/browse/C:/Shivanand/ReadMe.txt**

I am trying to commit ReadMe.txt file from path C:/Shivanand.

Below is the error ->

** Method Not Allowed
The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL **

I am using PUT method.

Comment: BitBucket has no access to your local C: drive. I doubt your repo contains a directory named `C:` (which would be an invalid name on Windows at least). The REST APIs of BitBucket are [documented](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/).

Comment: There's [Using WorkTree API to create commits in a repository](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/using-worktree-api-to-create-commits/) in the BitBucket docs.